# HighCharts: Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute

Tags: parsing, extjs, highcharts, extjs-mvc

I have ExtJs + Highcharts code like here:

```
Ext.define('Cabinet.view.workspace.indexCharts.Line', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.IndexLineChart',
    show: function (chartDiv, valuesList) {
        valuesList = '[' + valuesList + ']';
        console.log(valuesList);
        charts[chartDiv] = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: chartDiv,
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Some Title'
            },
            yAxis: {
                categories: [2005, 2006, 2007]
            },

            series: [{ data: valuesList}],

            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                align: 'center'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But after I call this widget, I get some error:

> Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute.
>
> `return e}function oa(a){return Fa(a)?a:[a]}function p(){var a=arguments,b,c,d=a`

console.log displayed: [825557000000,1089384000000,1404492600000]

Where is the problem in that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like valuesList is a string, what it needs to be is an array.

You need to convert it into an array before passing it to highchart, you can do it in various ways like

```
valuesList = '[' + valuesList + ']';
valuesList = JSON.parse(valuesList);
//OR
valuesList = jQuery.parse(valuesList);
//OR
valuesList = eval(valuesList);
```

Choose the one that suits you
Check out [parsing string to array @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/3spMx/) To understand some more on whats happening

Comment: Thank you, @Jugal. Some times later, I understood what I need convert this string. I try some like this: `valuesList = valuesList.map(function (x) { return parseFloat(x) });` And that works great! Thanks again. **Problem solved**.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `series.data` object needs a value that's an array of data points, but you're providing it a string that contains a JSON representation of an array.  `valueList` needs to be an array of numbers instead of a string.

If `valueList` is an array of numbers coming in, then this line is converting it to a string:

```
valuesList = '[' + valuesList + ']';
```

Don't do that.

Comment: valuesList its array of string(values).